# Difference between internal and no linkage

Tags: c++, c, scope, linkage

Please refer to the following code that is in the same translation unit:

```
static int global_var; // file scope in C and global namespace scope in C++
                       // internal linkage
void f(void)
{
    static int local_var; // block scope in C and local scope in C++
                          // no linkage 
}
```

My understanding is this:

- I can refer to *global_var* from anywhere in the translation unit because it has global scope.
- I can refer to *local_var* only inside function *f* because it has local scope.

My questions:

1. What is the difference beteen the two variables, in relation to linkage?
2. Can you provide one example where **internal** and **no linkage** makes a difference, and the difference is derived not only from scope?

**EDIT**
After the answer and comments of James Kanze, I am now able to construct an example that shows the difference between the internal and no linkage attributes:

```
static int i; // definition
              // static storage
              // internal linkage

void f(void)
{
    extern int i; // declaration
                  // refers to the static i at file scope
                  // note that even though the specifier is extern
                  // its linkage is intern (this is legal in both C/C++)
    {
        int i; // definition
               // automatic storage
               // no linkage
    }
}
```

Some articles that do a good job at explaining the concepts involved:

- [Scope regions in C and C++](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4026148/Scope-regions-in-C-and-C-) 
- [Storage class specifiers and storage duration](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4026823/Storage-class-specifiers-and-storage-duration) 
- [Linkage in C and C++](http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4007522/Linkage-in-C-and-C-)

Comment: Internal linkage refers to everything only in scope of a translation unit

Comment: Looks like homework, right?

Comment: @NirMH Actualy I would be very interested of where this type of homeworks are asked. The answer is no, this is not my homework. I asked this question to clarify my understanding of linkage and scope in C++.

Comment: Local scope implies no linkage, namespace scope can be either internal or external, class scope (at least in a non-local class) is always external.

Comment: @JamesKanze since c++11 there is no `Local scope`, only `block scope`. standard wording: `a name declared at block scope (6.3.3) has no linkage`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First: in addition to type, variables have three other
characteristics: linkage, scope and lifetime.  All four
attributes are sort of orthogonal, but linked in the way they
are expressed in the language, and do interact in some ways.

With regards to linkage: linkage really affects the symbol which
is being declared, and not the object itself.  If there is no
linkage, all declarations of the symbol bind to different
objects, e.g.:

```
int
func()
{
    int i;
    {
        int i;
    }
}
```

The symbol `i` has no linkage, and the two symbols `i` are bound
to two different entities.  Generally speaking, local variables
(variables declared at block scope) and function arguments have
no linkage, regardless of type and lifetime.

Internal and external linkage are similar, in that repeated
declarations of the symbol bind to the same entity: internal
linkage binds only within the translation unit, external accross
the entire program.  So given:

```
static int i;   //  internal linkage...
```

in several translation units, the `i` binds to a separate entity
in each translation unit.  Without the static, you have external
linkage, and all of the `i` bind to the same entity.

Note that this only holds at namespace scope; *all* entities
which are members of a non-local class have external linkage.

And that type has an impact: variables which are const
implicitly have internal linkage:

```
int const i = 42;    //  same as static int const i...
extern int const j = 42;    //  external linkage.
```

Finally, all declarations which bind to the same entity must
declare it to have the same type.  If you violate this rule in
a single translation unit (e.g.:

```
extern int i;
//   ...
double i;
```

in the same namespace scope), then the compiler should complain.
If the two declarations are in different translation units,
however, it is undefined behavior, and who knows what will
happen.  (In theory, the linker could complain, but most don't.)

EDIT:

One additional point: linkage is determined by the first
declaration which can refer to the entity.  So if I write:

```
static int i;

void
func()
{
    extern int i;
}
```

Both `i` refer to the same entity, which has internal linkage.
(Why one would ever write the second declaration is beyond me,
but it is legal.)

Comment: @GradyPlayer sorry I did not asked the question that you wanted me to ask. I am not asking a general question about linkage, I am asking specificaly about **internal** and **no linkage** i.e. same translation unit.

Comment: @zephon, it is just semantics, what symbols go where in the object so they can be accessed... if that really is the question that you want answered it will have a different answer for a different ABI, and you can inspect the ASM output of a compiler to see what they are doing... it also has a semantic difference dealing with optimizations - but not a big one, because it only has to resolve the symbol within the one compilation unit before it can discard it if it isn't used.

Comment: @zephon I realized that later; you do seem to understand many of the differences.  If you read carefully, you'll find that I did answer the question you asked, among many other things.  Look at the first example and the very last one (after my edit).

Comment: You are sugesting that the two *i* sybols bind to different entities because they have internal linkage. Please refer to Example 2 of my post. Why is the second *i* a different entity?

Comment: @zephon Because the second `i` has _no_ linkage.  The language is not always orthogonal with regards to how linkage is determined; a variable declaration at block scope has no linkage unless it is declared `extern`, in which case it has external linkage _if_ there is no preceding declaration at namespace scope, or the linkage of the preceding declaration if there is one.  It's what I tried to say in my first paragraph: the four characteristics are sort of orthogonal, except that they do sometimes interact.

Comment: @GradyPlayer My intention is to understand the semantics of internal linkage(vs no linkage) from a C/C++ programmers point of view. But if I can get a different results for a different ABI, doesn't that mean that it is not defined?

Comment: @JamesKanze I believe the reason why in my example the two *i* s are different, is because the second declaration is also a definition which shadows the first *i* definition. In your example the second declaration is not a defintion. You are right, the language lets you do such things as changing a declaration specifier from static to extern, but not the other way: first declaring extern, than static is undefined.

Comment: @zephon It's linked.  If two declarations bind to the same entity, only one can be a definition.  In your second example, one could just as easily say that the second declaration of `i` is a definition _because_ it has no linkage to attach it to the first declaration/definition.  How linkage works is fairly orthogonal to the other attributes, but how a declaration determines linkage is a complicated mix of things; the standard takes three pages to describe it.  In block scope, function declarations and names declared with `extern` have linkage, other names don't.

Comment: @JamesKanze [This](http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4007522/Linkage-in-C-and-C-) article explains very well some of the important details of linkage. If we talk about C++, then it very well explains that *extern int i;* is a non-defining declaration and *static int i;* is a declaration. In your example, there is one definition and one non-defining declaration => one entity and in mine there are two definitions => two entites.

Comment: My conclusion is that **variable shadowing** is possible because of the **no linkage** property. If my conclusion is correct than your answer is complete.

Comment: @zephon Formally: shadowing is concerned with scope, not linkage (and it's possible to shadow with linkage, e.g. `extern in i;` in an inner block will shadow an `i` defined in an outer block, and be shadowed by an `i` in a nested block).  Practically, of course, at most one declaration with linkage can be involved in shadowing, and you have to jump through hoops to get it involved; the no linkage property is certainly necessary for some of the declarations involved.

Comment: @JamesKanze Refering to your example, when *extern int i;* is encountered, this is a declaration with external linkage. At the next *int i;* in an inner block, this will be a declaration (and a definition), with no linkage. If it would have internal linkage then it would conflict with a previous definition, because two definitions are found. That is how I explain to myself the difference between internal and no linkage.

Comment: @zephon Yes, but `extern int i;` can shadow `int i;`.  That's my only point: shadowing is an effect of and on scope, not on linkage.

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree on your point, shadowing is an effect of and on scope. My addition to this, is that it is made possible by the existance of the no linkage attribute (at least in this example).

Comment: @zephon Generally, yes.  (A local declaration `extern int i;` can hide a member variable `i`, but I'm not sure hiding member variables would be called shadowing.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Is there is a formal definition of variable shadowing? I see it more as a result/consequence of certain combinations of linkage and scope attributes.

Comment: @zephon I don't know.  The standard uses the terms _potential scope_ and _scope_; the potential scope is the scope the symbol would have if there wasn't a declaration inside that scope.  So if I have something like: `struct C { int b; void f() { extern int b; } };`, if we consider shadowing to be the potential scope minus the scope, `extern int b;` shadows `C::b` in `C::f()`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thank you for your clarifications. I have edited my answer to add an example that shows the difference that I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `static` variables have internal linkage. You can't access the `static` variable or function in another file(in multiple file compilation situations), because its scope limited within this file(Internal linkage).
Normally `auto` and `register` variables have no linkage.

---

As i said above `auto` and `register` variables have no linkage. You can't declare these variables in global scope. `static` variables has internal linkage, scope is based on declaration, but not possible to access in another file. `extern` variables has external linkage, its possible to access these variables in another file.

For more reference [Storage classes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_storage_classes.htm)

Comment: No, `local_var` has no linkage, since it's declared at block scope. Storage duration has nothing to do with linkage, which is (mostly) determined by scope.

Comment: The document you link to is completely wrong (with sections like "external storage class", which doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

`global_var` could be accessed from `void g()` in the same compilation unit, that is the difference.

Comment: accessing global_var by using its name is a property of its scope, not linkage